# Cómo manejar imagenes en nodejs desde la base de datos?

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Estoy realizando un proyecto utilizando MySQL para la persistencia de datos. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es guardar y mostrar imágenes en la base de datos pero no se como lograr esto, alguien conoce o me puede ayudar en como hacer esto con NodeJS?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español, por favor podrías añadir el código que tienes o has intentado? Nos ayudaría mucho a solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Podrías "encodear" en **base64** el binario de la imagen, de esta forma sólo almacenas en la base de datos un String. Que luego cuando necesites recuperar la imagen harías el decode de String a binario.

[Este articulo](https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-node-js/) está en ingles pero expresa bien lo que estoy trantando de decir utilizando código de ejemplo.